# How to decode Client Cookie strings in `javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie`

Tags: java, jax-rs

How does one decode Client Cookies strings jax-rs? What I mean by this is how do you convert a String cookie value into a `javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie`?

Here is an example of how to do it in Netty:

`Cookie myCookie = ClientCookieDecoder.LAX.decode("my cookie string here")`

Does anyone know of a useful utility method equivalent of this for jax rs?

Comment: Why are *you* trying to do this? The Jax-RS runtime will do it for you, i.e. it will decode the cookie header of the incoming request and make the `Cookie` available to you. You just need to add `Cookie` parameter to your handler method.

Comment: the cookie stored via string from a third party system. i want to turn it into a cookie to send thru jersey now

Comment: Where is the string coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method that works:

```
Cookie cookie = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createHeaderDelegate(Cookie.class).fromString(cookieStringValue);
```

Note: Don't use

```
Cookie.valueOf(cookieStringValue)
```

because it is deprecated.